# Lists of list manipulation

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My code is the following:

```
import itertools

lists = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]

names = [item[0] for item in lists]
for x in lists:
    del x[0]

answer = {name:set(L) for name,L in zip(names, lists)}
```

which gives me:

```
{0: {1}, 1: {2, 8}, 3: {4}, 4: {2}, 2: {5}, 5: {6, 7}, 8: {9, 10, 11, 12}}
```

But what I want to have is to add a key of a previous items for each of the entries. What I want is to have

```
{0:{1},1:{0,2,8},3:{1,4},4:{3,2} (...)}
```

Futhermore I would like to twist it a little I mean as a key I want to have each number I have on a list e.g. as I have `5:{6,7}` i want to have as well `6:{5,7}` and `7:{5,6}` obviously i should not have any duplicates.

My question is how could i achieve this?

To make myself clearer I want to visualize a the following graph:

[image: LINK]

Comment: dict keys have to be unique. Are you sure that there're any two lists which have same first element?

Comment: Should "and `{7,6}`" read "and `7:{5,6}` ?

Comment: @Blorgbeard my mistake yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with defaultdict from collections:

```
lists = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]

from collections import defaultdict
edges  = [ (V[0],Vn) for V in lists for Vn in V[1:] ]
result = next( d for d in [defaultdict(set)] if [d[a].add(b) or d[b].add(a) for a,b in edges])
print( dict(result))
# {0: {1}, 1: {0, 8, 2}, 2: {1, 4, 5}, 8: {1, 9, 10, 11, 12}, 3: {4}, 4: {2, 3}, 5: {2, 6, 7}, 6: {5}, 7: {5}, 9: {8}, 10: {8}, 11: {8}, 12: {8}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it unlikely you would want to make a dict of all permutations of each list as you have a duplicate numbers in a couple of them so possibly making a list of all the dicts *(of which being the permutations of each list)* then you could do this:

```
from itertools import permutations

lists = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]

answer = [{k:set(v) for k, *v in perms} for perms in map(permutations, lists)]
```

Output for this being:

```
[{0: {1}, 1: {0}}, {1: {8, 2}, 2: {8, 1}, 8: {1, 2}}, {3: {4}, 4: {3}}, {4: {2}, 2: {4}}, {2: {5}, 5: {2}}, {5: {6, 7}, 6: {5, 7}, 7: {5, 6}}, {8: {9, 10, 11, 12}, 9: {8, 10, 11, 12}, 10: {8, 9, 11, 12}, 11: {8, 9, 10, 12}, 12: {8, 9, 10, 11}}]
```

Otherwise if you don’t mind losing some of the values to being overwritten then you could use this comprehension

```
answer = {k:set(v) for perms in map(permutations, lists) for k, *v in perms}
```

Output of this being:

```
{0: {1}, 1: {8, 2}, 2: {5}, 8: {9, 10, 11, 12}, 3: {4}, 4: {2}, 5: {6, 7}, 6: {5, 7}, 7: {5, 6}, 9: {8, 10, 11, 12}, 10: {8, 9, 11, 12}, 11: {8, 9, 10, 12}, 12: {8, 9, 10, 11}}
```

Comment: Great answer appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
lists = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
answer = {lists[i][0]: set(([lists[i - 1][0]] if i > 0 else []) + lists[i][1:]) for i in range(len(lists))}
```

Comment: This doesn't provide what the OP is requesting

Comment: @Wondercricket, he edited question after I've answered -_-

Comment: No he didn't, the only edit was a small formatting correction, and it was after your answer.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, before he provided example of output, I was sure that he need exatly that.

Comment: @Blorgbeard OP might have edited within the grace period, which I think is 5 minutes for questions.

Comment: Looks good, upvoted. I don't think it addresses the "furthermore" part of the question though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, it's impossible to achieve using `dict` cause keys should be unique. With provided input code will generate duplicates.

Comment: actually, it will generate duplicates with any input, cause we add previous key into set -_-

Comment: Yes it does not address the futhermore part of the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to build a `names` list: destructuring assignment will do the trick.

```
>>> lists = [[0,1], [1,2,8], [3,4], [4,2], [2,5], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
>>> answer = {name:set(L) for name,*L in lists}
>>> answer
{0: {1}, 1: {8, 2}, 3: {4}, 4: {2}, 2: {5}, 5: {6, 7}, 8: {9, 10, 11, 12}}
```

Now, you want to add the previous `name` when you compute the current `name:list`. You just have to `zip` the list with itself to get the expected result:

```
>>> answer = {name2:set([name1]+L2) for (name1,*L1), (name2,*L2) in zip([[lists[0][1]]]+lists, lists)}
>>> answer
{0: {1}, 1: {0, 8, 2}, 3: {1, 4}, 4: {2, 3}, 2: {4, 5}, 5: {2, 6, 7}, 8: {5, 9, 10, 11, 12}}
```

The trick is to add an element before the first version of the list that will not change the first `name:list`. If you use `[lists[0][1]]`, the first `name1` is part of the first `list2` and the `set` will be unchanged.

Comment: But what i want to have is as well in my dictionary is a key of value  6,7,9,10,11,12 etc.